# How can I health check all running fargate tasks for a service individually without target groups and ELB?

Tags: aws-fargate, health-check

I am working on a project and I have been tasked with developing a solution for health checking all of the running fargate tasks for a specific service- it runs on 2 by default, but can expand out to 10 tasks depending on resource utilization. The tricky part is that the architecture does not utilize target groups and ELB, but instead cloudmap/apigw/r53 for service discovery and dns routing. I imagined creating a lambda function that would find out what the running tasks are for that service, send a request to the actuator endpoint for each running task, and then collect the responses and publish to cloudwatch. Is it possible to direct a request to a specific fargate task? Is there a service in AWS that I can utilize to work around the fact that ELB isn't being utilized?

So far I haven't attempted implementing anything since I am in the research process, but any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use container health checks? https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/03/amazon-ecs-supports-container-health-checks-and-task-health-mana/

Comment: Is it possible to publish health check results to cloudwatch? One of the requirements is to create a dashboard where these things can be visualized.

Comment: You have to write some custom script code to perform container health checks. You could have that code also send a metric value to CloudWatch if you wanted.